# when i try to download folder on s3 file using file manager in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, download, php-ziparchive

When I tried download folder on s3 file using file manager in Laravel getting Zip Archive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied

I tried this command in my ubuntu server "chmod 1777 /tmp" and check "ls -ld /tmp" its getting "drwxrwxrwt"

but still getting Zip Archive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Permission denied

Comment: Please put some more focus in your question. You said download folder, but then you said the error is with a zip archive. You're mentioning S3 but in the end it's a ZipArchive::close error. Try simplifying and isolating the problem. Also consider using [getStatusString()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getstatusstring.php) before and after calling close().